# Tomcat image doesn't start on Docker when providing tomcat-users.xml

Tags: java, tomcat, docker

I'm new to Docker and to CI in general. I'm also pretty bad when I need to set up a server.

What I want is simply to have a Docker image running Tomcat and having the possibility to (re)deploy my new app version using the Tomcat deploy plugin from Ttravis (in the after_success section).

I'm modifying the 7.0 Tomcat version of this repository : https://github.com/tutumcloud/tutum-docker-tomcat

It I don't change anything, the server is able to start, but I'm not able to access the manager nor to deploy my code.

I want a directory called `conf/` in my host, this directory will be copier to the `tomcat/conf directory`.

In order to connect to the manager/deploy my code I need to add `tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml` and `tomcat/conf/settings.xml files`.

I achieve this with this Dockerfile :

```
FROM tifayuki/java:7
MAINTAINER Feng Honglin <hfeng@tutum.co>
RUN apt-get update && \
apt-get install -yq --no-install-recommends wget pwgen ca-certificates && \
apt-get clean && \
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
ENV TOMCAT_MAJOR_VERSION 7
ENV TOMCAT_MINOR_VERSION 7.0.55
ENV CATALINA_HOME /tomcat
# INSTALL TOMCAT
RUN wget -q https://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-${TOMCAT_MAJOR_VERSION}/v${TOMCAT_MINOR_VERSION}/bin/apache-tomcat-${TOMCAT_MINOR_VERSION}.tar.gz && \
wget -qO- https://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-${TOMCAT_MAJOR_VERSION}/v${TOMCAT_MINOR_VERSION}/bin/apache-tomcat-${TOMCAT_MINOR_VERSION}.tar.gz.md5 | md5sum -c - && \
tar zxf apache-tomcat-*.tar.gz && \
rm apache-tomcat-*.tar.gz && \
mv apache-tomcat* tomcat
ADD create_tomcat_admin_user.sh /create_tomcat_admin_user.sh
ADD run.sh /run.sh
ADD conf/ /tomcat/conf/       # THIS LINES ADD MY TOMCAT-USER FILE
RUN chmod +x /*.sh
EXPOSE 8080
```

Here is the tomcat-users.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<tomcat-users>
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<user username="admin" password="vT0nZAuK4tGp" roles="manager-gui,manager-script" />
</tomcat-users>
```

My startup commande :

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 gmas/tomcat
```

You can see all my files there : https://github.com/GiveMeAShow/docker

The git repository only contains files necessary to my docker conf so it's very small.

About my log files :

- docker logs  returns nothing
- /etc/var/logs doesn't
- contain any tomcat directory tomcat/logs is empty

Comment: Could you please put tomcat logs to gists? Maybe it contains some useful information

Comment: Hi, How can I achieve that ?
docker logs <container> returns nothing

Comment: Hope you're not using that password anywhere...

Comment: Ahah no xD, it was auto generated by one of the sh files. Just playing with it's raw value to test if tomcat accept the deployment (if it's up).

Comment: try ` ADD /conf/ /tomcat/conf/`and let us know

Comment: Hi, same problem, nothing in logs and still not started

Comment: Tomcat stores its log under /tomcat/log/ folder in your case, in many files. Try read over them. I think docker logs will not return with any log because tomcat usually does not log to stderr/stdout/syslog.

Comment: It is empty too ^^. O moved to use dokku on my server :)! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When using

```
ADD/COPY pathtofile /tomcat/pathtofile
```

or

```
run -v /host/pathtofile:/container/pathtofile
```

check **the access rights** for the host file. If not sufficient, do

```
sudo chmod 777 /host/pathtofile
```